# Prove $v = \sqrt{\frac{2gRh}{R + h}}$ from Given (below)

Tags: calculus, physics, mathematical-physics, applications

Given:

$$F = \frac{mgR^2}{(x + R)^2}$$

$m = \text{mass}$

$g = \text{Acceleration due to gravity}$

$x = x(t)$ is the object's distance above the surface at time $t$.

I believe this is the *Universal Law of Gravitation* (correct me if I am wrong)

Also by Newton's Second Law, $F = ma = m\left(\dfrac{dv}{dt}\right).$

The question reads:

Suppose a rocket is first vertically upward with an initial velocity $v$. Let $h$ be the maximum height above the surface reached by the object. Show that:

$$v = \sqrt{\frac{2gRh}{R + h}}.$$

At the bottom of the problem it says:
Hint: by the chain rule $$m\frac{dv}{dt} = mv\frac{dv}{dx}$$

If it isn't too much trouble, how did the textbook writers get this result using chain rule?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Since $v=dx/dt$, by the chain rule, we get the following [separable differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Ordinary_differential_equations_.28ODE.29)
$$mv\frac{dv}{dx}=m\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=m\frac{dv}{dt}=ma = F = -\frac{mgR^2}{(x + R)^2}$$
(note that minus sign, the gravitation force is attractive!).
Then by integrating we get
$$\int_{v_0}^0v{dv}=-\int_0^{h}\frac{gR^2}{(x + R)^2}{dx}$$
that is
$$\left[\frac{v^2}{2}\right]_{v_0}^0 =\left[\frac{gR^2}{x + R}\right]_0^{h}\implies -\frac{v_0^2}{2}=\frac{gR^2}{(h + R)}-\frac{gR^2}{R}\implies v_0 = \sqrt{\frac{2gRh}{R + h}}$$
where $v_0$ is the initial velocity and $h$ the maximum height above the surface reached by the object (at that point the velocity of the object is zero).

P.S. Note that for $h\to +\infty$ the above result gives the formula of the [escape velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity), i.e. $v_e=\sqrt{2gR}$.

Comment: This was a very helpful explanation but I'm confused as to why you integrated from 0 to v-initial and from 0 to h, respectively.

Comment: @Ikechukwu Anude Because  when $x=0$ (initial height) then $v=v_0$ (initial velocity) and when $x=h$ (the maximum height) then $v=0$ (velocity at the maximum height). The velocity $v$ decreases from $v_0$ to $0$ due to the gravity then it changes sign and the object falls ack. Is it clear now?

Comment: Thank you so much, I was in the same problem and this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$v=\frac{dx}{dt}$$
we have
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dv}{dx}$$